# Manjaro AUR install: what is the difference between "makepkg -s" then "pacman -U *.tar.xz" vs "makepkg -si"

Tags: manjaro, pacman, aur, makepkg

In Manjaro is there any functional difference between using

```
makepkg -s
```

followed by then running

```
pacman -U <package_name>.tar.xz
```

instead of just using

```
makepkg -si
```

?
I've seen them both used in instructions for installing programs from AUR, and I was curious if there was any significant difference between the two processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no functional difference between the two. Infact 'makepkg -i' calls 'pacman -U' in the backend.

From my understanding, the only reason the 'makepkg -i' option exists is to streamline the build process with a single tool using a single command.

Source: `$ man makepkg`